# placing the callback value in a variable outside the callback (using esm) Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can anyone help me with this?

error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined

```
import mongodb from 'mongodb';

class database {
    static client;

    static getdb(dbname) {
        return this.client;
    }

    static connect(mongostring) {
        (mongodb.MongoClient).connect(mongostring, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, function (err, db) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(`not connected on mongodb!`);
                process.exit();
            }
            this.client = db;
            console.log(`connected in mongodb!`)
        })
    }
}

export default database;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult for me to verify these suggestions, so please let me know which worked for you. :)

Suggestion #1: Using a local variable `that`.

```js
static connect(mongostring) {
    let that = this;  // <<== ADDED THIS LINE
    (mongodb.MongoClient).connect(mongostring, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, function (err, db) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(`not connected on mongodb!`);
            process.exit();
        }
        that.client = db;  // <<== CHANGED THIS LINE
        console.log(`connected in mongodb!`)
    })
}
```

Suggestion #2: Arrow functions will not bind `this`:

```js
static connect(mongostring) {
    (mongodb.MongoClient).connect(mongostring, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, db) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(`not connected on mongodb!`);
            process.exit();
        }
        this.client = db;
        console.log(`connected in mongodb!`)
    })
}
```

Comment: Where exactly do you get the error? Could you share the code (from the other file) that uses your shared code above, and leads to raising that error?

Comment: Also, are you sure that Suggestion #1 didn't work? (I've just added comments to emphasize which lines were changed)

Comment: something went wrong but with the first solution I managed to fix my code thank you very much